# Problem with Installing Wi-Fi Driver on Debian

Tags: debian, apt, wifi, drivers

I have just downloaded Debian Live onto my USB. Currently, I am unable to connect to the internet in Debian. I am trying to install the driver for my Broadcom BCM4360 chip according to instructions from https://wiki.debian.org/wl. However, I am having a problem with the `apt-get update` step. When I run it, I get this:

```
Err http://http.debian.net jessie InRelease
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
Err http://http.debian.net jessie Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'http.debian.net'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'http.debian.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Is it possible to run `apt-get-update` without an internet connection?

Comment: run `aptitude update` first and try again

Comment: Can you temporarily connect by a cable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot update your repos' database fetching the new ones' content from the Internet, without having an Internet Connection. You could update it only from a local device (i.e. cd-rom).
It's not a matter of apt-get that you can workaround with aptitude. You just need an Internet connection.
If you don't have one nor can in any way solve this issue (for example with usb tethering and a phone), then use another device to download the packages you need and its dependencies from a mirror in .deb format and install them with dpkg.
For example

```
https://packages.debian.org/jessie/broadcom-sta-dkms
```

will let you download what you need for your version and tell you wich are dependencies.